# How to render a qweb template by action button?

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-15

I have Qweb template like this:

```
<template id="test_template">
    <h1>My template</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('it works');
    </script>
    <div>
        <t t-foreach="my_items" t-as="item">
            ...
        </t>
    </div>
</template>
```

I can render it in website by a controller like this

```
@http.route('/test_template', type="http", auth="user", methods=['GET'], website=True)
    def test_template(self, **kw):
        return request.render('my_module.test_template', {'my_items': [1, 2, 3]})
```

but I want to be able to render this template not in a separate website tab, but in the framework itself directly, as it works with actions and views
[image]

any ideas, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo transforms a `<template>` element into a `<record>` (`ir.ui.view` in this case) and will not be available to the JavaScript qweb renderer function.

You can define a client action and use `_rpc` to call a model function to render the template and return the result

***Example:***  *Call `ir.ui.view` render template function*

```
return self.env["ir.ui.view"]._render_template("my_module.test_template", 
    {'my_items': items}
)
```

***EDIT*** Add A custom view to render QWEB

```py
class ActWindowView(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.actions.act_window.view'

    view_mode = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('qweb_view', "QWEB View")], ondelete={'qweb_view': 'cascade'})


class View(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'ir.ui.view'

    type = fields.Selection(selection_add=[('qweb_view', "QWEB View")], ondelete={'qweb_view': 'cascade'})
```

Add the following JS code under `assets/web.assets_backend` in the manifest file:

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import { Renderer, Controller, View } from 'web.qweb';
import registry from 'web.view_registry';


var QwebController = Controller.extend({
    init: function (parent, model, renderer, params) {
        params.withControlPanel = false;
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },
});

var QwebRenderer = Renderer.extend({
    _render: function () {
        var self = this;
        return this._super.apply(this, arguments).then(function () {
            self.$el.html(self.state.body);
            $('head').append(self.$el.find('script'));
        });
    },
});

var QwebView = View.extend({
    config: _.extend({}, View.prototype.config, {
        Controller: QwebController,
        Renderer: QwebRenderer,
    }),
    viewType: 'qweb_view',
    groupable: false,
});

registry.add('qweb_view', QwebView);
```

Define a `qweb_view` view to call your template and use it in the window action:

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="company_structure_test">
   <field name="name">company.structure.qweb</field>
   <field name="model">res.company</field>
   <field name="mode">primary</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <qweb_view>
            <t t-call="qweb_view.company_structure_test_template">
                <t t-set="model" t-value="res_company"/>
            </t>
        </qweb_view>
    </field>
</record>
        
<record id="action_company_structure" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Структура компанії</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.company</field>
    <field name="view_mode">qweb_view</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="company_structure_test"/>
</record>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I found a solution to my question and described it below in a separate answer. But with such an implementation, the js does not work in the web template. Perhaps you have faced such a problem before?

Comment: No, I didn't use qweb templates with window actions. You can create a custom qweb view and use `t-call` directive to render the template. This will let you execute custom js code directly from the view controller

Comment: can you please write an example, how to achieve this?

Comment: I've added a minimal example

Comment: thank you very much for your hard work, everything works great except for one point that simple js code for example
<script type="text/javascript">
     console.log('it works');
</script>
  is not executed either in the qweb_view or in the <template> itself. Is it possible to fix?

Comment: The script will be executed when the template is rendered from a controller. For the qweb view, you can create a custom renderer and override the `_render` function to move the script to the header. Check my edit

Comment: oh my god, it really works. my respect and boundless gratitude to you for the work you had done.

Answer (score 0):

you a typical view to be inherit the settings view **base.res_config_settings_view_form**. like the following:

```xml
<record id="res_config_settings_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">res.config.settings.view.form.inherit.account</field>
  <field name="model">res.config.settings</field>
  <field name="priority" eval="40"/>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.res_config_settings_view_form"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('settings')]" position="inside">
      <div class="app_settings_block" data-string="Invoicing" string="Invoicing" data-key="account" >
      
        <!-- Here all your code for sub-views -->


      </div>
    </xpath>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: sorry, but it`s not what i need.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys, I spent almost a month searching for a solution, unfortunately the answers were a bit off about what I was trying to implement, but I got it at some point.

We can use ir.actions.act_window with "qweb" view_mode to get this job done.

```
<record id="action_company_structure" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Структура компанії</field>
    <field name="res_model">res.company</field>
    <field name="view_mode">qweb</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="tada.company_structure_test"/>
</record>
```

here is my test template

```
<template id="company_structure_test">
    <h1>qweb works</h1>
    <t t-set="test_data" t-value="model.get_company_structure_data()"/>
    <p t-esc="test_data"/>
    <p t-esc="test_data['test_str']"/>
    <p t-esc="test_data['test_list'][-1]"/>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        console.log('this don`t work');
    </script>
</template>
```

and result:
[image]
I'm under the impression that it shouldn't work at all, but somehow it does in this format. The panel at the top can be simply hidden using a js script, if necessary

but there is a problem if you want to use js. I tried but it didn't work. i encountered the same problem when using request.render('my_template',{}). If you render your template in website, js works. If in odoo itself or on empty page, js didn`t work. there is no console.log in browser console.